# Optimizer adding energy into unused storage system

Tags: python, gekko

I am currently making a model where I will be integrated Battery and thermal energy storage with a nuclear power plant on a power grid. I have made my model so that it will run both types of power storage seperately correctly. The issue that I am having is that when I comment one of the storages out so that it is not involved in storing the energy somehow in the first 2 timesteps it gets half of its over all capacity in energy even though it is disconnected. When I comment the other system out the same issue happens to the power system that is commented out. Do you know what is causing this?

Here is my code for it. I have simplified it down so that I can include all of it.

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad

#Set up basic power consumption data
n = 24
t = np.linspace(0,n,n)
def load(t):
    return  -10*np.sin(2*np.pi*t/24)+40
Load = load(t)
Gen = np.ones(n)*40
def need(t):
    return 10*np.sin(2*np.pi*t/24)+10

#Set up Model
m = GEKKO()
m.time = t

Cons = m.Param(value=Load)
Enuc = m.FV(value=45, lb=0) #nuclear power
Enuc.STATUS = 1

#Thermal Energy Storage
T = m.SV(value=300,ub=500,lb=300)
mass = m.FV(value=.0746,lb=0)
mass.STATUS=0
Cp = m.Param(value=5)
thermaleff = .8   #80%efficient
thermeff = m.if3((Enuc - Cons)/(mass*Cp),1/thermaleff,thermaleff)

#Battery Electrical storage
Capacity = 76.2
EStored = m.SV(value=0,lb=0,ub=Capacity)
batteryeff = .95
batteff = m.if3((Enuc - Cons),1/batteryeff,batteryeff)

#Energy Balance 
Cost = m.Var()

m.Equation(EStored.dt() == batteff*(Enuc - Cons))  #Energy balance for Battery
#m.Equation(T.dt() == thermeff*(Enuc - Cons)/(mass*Cp)) #Energy balance for Thermal Storage
m.Equation(Cost == Enuc*1000 + Capacity*1000 + mass*5000)
m.Obj(Cost)

m.options.IMODE = 5
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.solve()

#plot
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(t,Load)
plt.plot(t,Enuc.value)

plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.plot(t,EStored.value, label=f'Capacity = {EStored.value[12]:.03}')
plt.title("Battery Storage")
plt.ylabel("Energy")
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.plot(t,T.value,label=f'mass = {mass.value[-1]:.03}')
plt.title("Thermal Storage")
plt.ylabel("Temperature(K)")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are eliminating the equation but the variable is still adjustable by the optimizer. The optimizer determines that it can fill up the storage for free without the equation. You could try the following instead to switch on or off the ability to do battery or thermal energy storage.

```py
# select battery or thermal storage
battery_storage = True
thermal_storage = True
if battery_storage:
    # Energy balance for Battery
    m.Equation(EStored.dt() == batteff*(Enuc - Cons))
else:
    # Battery storage off
    m.Equation(EStored.dt() == 0)
if thermal storage:
    # Energy balance for Thermal Storage
    m.Equation(T.dt() == thermeff*(Enuc - Cons)/(mass*Cp)) 
else:
    # Thermal storage off
    m.Equation(T.dt() == 0)
```

[image: Energy Storage Results]

Another option is to define the decision variables as Manipulated Variables and turn the `STATUS` on (1) or off (0) depending on whether the optimizer can use those.
Another option (more condensed) is to use `battery_storage` parameter directly in the equation as `m.Equation(EStored.dt() == battery_storage*batteff*(Enuc - Cons))`. When `battery_storage` is zero (off) then it will set the derivative to zero. You could do the same for `thermal_storage`. If you make `battery_storage` and `thermal_storage` an adjustable parameter as a Gekko variable then you can turn them on or off as the simulation runs cycle-to-cycle.

Comment: Thank you that is super helpful